# Android Virtual Device does not open on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I just opened up Android Studio for the first time. I added a few buttons and text fields. I then opened up my AVD Manager and hit run on the Nexus 5 that comes pre installed.  It says starting AVD and then after that finishes, the AVD pops up in the bottom task bar but no new window pops up showing my virtual device like it did in the tutorial.  Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: "the AVD pops up in the bottom task bar but no new window pops up showing my virtual device" - I think that is contradictory

Comment: @cricket_007 in the run section of the bottom panel it says AVD Nexus 5 and but there is no new window that shows an actual virtual phone... I thought that was supposed to happen.  If not how can I test my app?

Comment: Have you ran the app itself, or did you just start the AVD?

Comment: @cricket_007 I started the AVD and then ran the app with the run app button on top